# Passing images between View Controllers

Tags: objective-c, ios, image, cocoa-touch

First of all, I'm new to XCode and programming and my English is not perfect.
I have 2 view controllers, L1ViewController and ImageViewController. In the L1ViewController i have several buttons with an image as background. What I'm trying to do is when you click a button, the action passes a password and an image to the Image View controller. In the ImageViewController I have a UITextfield and a UIImageView. Passing the password string works fine. But passing the image seems harder than I thought. The UIImageView doesn't display the image.

In my L1ViewController.h I've created a

```
    -(IBAction)img1;
```

In my L1ViewController.m this is the code to pass the image and the passwordstring:

```
    -(IBAction)img1;
{
ImageViewController *img = [[ImageViewController alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myimage.jpg"] AndAnswerString:@"mypassword"];   
[self presentModalViewController:img animated:NO];
}
```

In my ImageViewController I have this code to receive the string and the image:

```
-(id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)inImage AndAnswerString:(NSString *)inAnswerString
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        [inImage release];
        [self setImage:inImage];
        [self setAnswerString:inAnswerString];

    }
    return self;
} 
-(void)setImage:(UIImage *)inImage
{
[inImage release];
[logoField setImage:inImage]; 
}

-(void)setAnswerString:(NSString *)inAnswerString
{
answerString = inAnswerString;
}
```

In my ImageViewController.h I've

```
@interface ImageViewController : UIViewController { 
IBOutlet UITextField *answerField;
IBOutlet UIImageView *logoField;

NSString *answerString;
 }

@property (nonatomic, retain)NSString *logo;
-(id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)inImage AndAnswerString:(NSString *)inAnswerString;
-(void)setImage:(UIImage *)inImage;
-(void)setAnswerString:(NSString *)inAnswerString;

-(IBAction)enterAnswer;
-(IBAction)back;
```

Why is my answerstring working fine but shows my ImageViewController no image?
Again, I'm new to XCode, maybe it's just a stupid fault.
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: make sure you retain the image, so its not removed from memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your view controller is being initialized, the views have not been loaded yet.  (That happens just before your `viewDidLoad:` method is called.)  Saving the string works because you're not trying to put it directly into `answerField` but, with the image, you're trying to update `logoField` too early.

If the text is working, you must have code somewhere that assigns `answerString` to `answerField`.

Comment: Thanks! I understand what is going wrong, but how do I solve this? You don't have to type it al out, I only need a push in the right direction... :)

Comment: Create a new property in your `ImageViewController` that holds a `UIImage` reference.  Set that to `inImage` in your initializer and then update `logoField` once the view has loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You have release "inImage" - before you have used,so remove the code "[inImage release];" from all the functions, Release it after you have use that image

so  the new code be.. the following

```
   -(id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)inImage AndAnswerString:(NSString *)inAnswerString
{
if (self = [super init])
{
    //[inImage release];
    [self setImage:inImage];
    [self setAnswerString:inAnswerString];

}
return self;
} 
-(void)setImage:(UIImage *)inImage
{
[logoField setImage:inImage]; 
[inImage release];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Stil doesn't work, I deleted all the releases and did what you say but the ImageView stays empty...

Answer (score 0):

ok ..I think you have to pass it as an id and not as UIImage witch doesn't work:
in your secondUIViewController.h:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) id image;
```

in secondViewController.m

```
@synthesize image = _image;
```